# What is the 'best' stat prioritisation for a Jedi Sentinel

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I jump in and out of playing SWTOR. I've recently returned to play this new Knights of the Fallen Empire story and the game seems to have changed, a lot.

As of this expansion, **what is the *'best'* stat prioritisation for dealing as much damage as possible as a dual-wielding Jedi Sentinel?**

(Ideally with abilities over auto-attacks)

EDIT: Currently using the **Combat** tree.

Comment: You should add which of the 3 trees that you usually play in, this can make a bit of a difference in terms of crit and accuracy

Comment: @Vahx That's a very good point, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exact optimal stats are: 6410 Endurance | 5372 Mastery | 2931 Power
1309 Critical | 774 Alacrity | 701 Accuracy

To achieve this, you want Versatile [armorings](https://torcommunity.com/database/item/wCtT4LB/advanced+versatile+armoring+43/) and [hilt](https://torcommunity.com/database/item/BlHvmeF/advanced+versatile+hilt+43/) (for more Mastery), unlettered [Lethal mods](https://torcommunity.com/database/item/tUsdov2/advanced+lethal+mod+43/) (for more Mastery and Power), 2 [Initiative enhancements](https://torcommunity.com/database/item/0u4mwuE/advanced+initiative+enhancement+43/) and 5 [Accuracy augments](https://torcommunity.com/database/item/gqC7SxB/advanced+accuracy+augment+40/) (to get almost exactly 110% Accuracy), and the rest split approximately 2:1 between Crit and Alacrity.  That means 2 [Eviscerating crystals](https://torcommunity.com/database/search/all/?name=Advanced+Eviscerating+Crystal), 3 [Crit](https://torcommunity.com/database/item/7ut8Hi8/advanced+critical+augment+40/) and 6 [Alacrity](https://torcommunity.com/database/item/qsXVV6C/advanced+alacrity+augment+40/) augments, and 6 [Adept](https://torcommunity.com/database/item/F3QIB3C/advanced+adept+enhancement+43/) and 2 [Quick Savant](https://torcommunity.com/database/item/gKBWpa9/advanced+quick+savant+enhancement+43/) enhancements.  Ideally, you want to get Hard Mode Operations tokens (Unassembled pieces) in order to exchange for [Weaponmaster gear](https://torcommunity.com/database/search/item?name=Weaponmaster&minrat=220&maxrat=220) (which has the Guardian DPS set bonus armorings).  Operations drops are also the only way to get the best Mods and Enhancements without crafting.

For the purposes of stat discussions, note that [Implants](https://torcommunity.com/database/search/item?name=Exarch%20Package%20MK-1&minrat=220&maxrat=220&fil=52:56:&filop=1:1&filval=0:0&qual=5) and [Earpieces](https://torcommunity.com/database/search/item?name=Exarch%20Device%20MK-1&minrat=220&maxrat=220&fil=52:56:&filop=1:1&filval=0:0&qual=5) count as Enhancements and are named similarly, with the addition of "MK-1" at the end for the best versions.

Please see [this forum post](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=847112) for the mathematics behind these recommendations. The short version is that as a DPS you will always prioritize other stats over Endurance and so choose the low-endurance modifications.  Crit is the most valuable stat but quickly enters diminishing returns as you acquire more of it — but Alacrity is also quite valuable and is affected much less by diminishing returns.  Power is always less valuable than Crit in 4.0 (given current stat budgets) despite it having no diminishing returns at all, and Mastery (formerly the 4 main stats)  continues to be heavily curbed.  Oh, and you want that extra 10% Accuracy because it overcomes boss resistances.

Comment: This is incredibly more comprehensive than I could have asked for thank you so much!

Comment: I knew you would give the better answer here  Matthew